# PySyde6 path of setWindowIcon didn't work with PyInstaller on Windows

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller, pyside6, pyqt6

I am following a step by step [tutorial](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/packaging-pyside6-applications-windows-pyinstaller-installforge/) on PySide6 and PyInstaller in order to do my first one-file build EXE application.

But I am stuck at the step "Setting an application icon". My window created with PySide6 doesn't display my logo icon when I build the source file with PyInstaller.

I have used `app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) , 'logo.ico')))` as described on the PySide6 tutorial to pass through relative path but it didn't work.
Then I have replaced `os.path` with `ntpath` because I am on Windows but it didn't work too.
I have tried with
`str(Path(__file__).parent / 'logo.ico')`
from pathlib but no more result either.

All of this path shows correctly the logo icon when I execute app.py from my IDE. However, when I build it with PyInstaller using this command `pyinstaller --onefile --icon=logo.ico -w .\app.py`, and launch app.exe there is no logo on my window. I don't know if path to my logo is the problem here but I don't see what else it could be.

Comment: In the link you posted there's a section explaining about "Bundling data files with PyInstaller". The `--icon` flag sets the icon for the file, doesn't bundle it as a resource, you must use `--add-data`, a spec file, or a compiled Qt resources file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as mentioned by @musicamante, I need to bundle my icon as a resource : `pyinstaller --windowed --icon=hand.ico --add-data="hand.ico;." app.py` or by modifying the datas list in the Analysis section of the spec file.